# Given an integer N and a set of operations, reduce N to 1 in the least amount of steps

Tags: algorithm

On a given integer N we can use the following operations:

1. If N can be divided by 3: divide by 3.
2. If N can be divided by 2: divide by 2.
3. Subtract 1.

How can I find a strategy to reach 1 in the least number of steps?

Comment: Are you saying the correct solution is 12, because ((12 / 3) / 2) - 1 = 1?

Comment: yes. in 10, ((10-1)/3)3) is correct solution, not (((10/2)-1)/2))/2.

Comment: @Nabla just one sufficient. in 10, answer is 3.

Comment: This reminds me a little of the [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), where the `3n+1` is the inverse of 2 of the steps here, and the `/2` covers the third one. I wonder if this suggests there's a better solution than brute force. Maybe worth a topic in one of the math SE sites.

Comment: @HyeonWooKim what if N is not divisible by 3,2 then what is to done ?

Comment: @VikramBhat I think the idea is that you have the option of dividing, but you aren't required to do so.

Answer (score 5):

As mbeckish mentioned you can treat this as a BFS traversal, which has significantly better time and space complexity than a bottom up DP approach. You can also apply a branch and bound (B&B) heuristic of sorts in the traversal such that you prune the branches of the tree at nodes that we've already seen the labeled value before. Unlike an actual B&B heuristic, this will not prune off the optimal solution since it does not involve any educated guesses of where the optimal solution might be. I'll give a visual example and have the algorithm reduce down to 0 to better illustrate.

Here is a full tree of operations reducing 10 to 0:

```
   --------10---------
   5         -----9----
---4---     -3-      ------8------  
2    -3-    1 2    --4--         7        
1    1 2    0 1    2  -3-   -----6------   
0    0 1      0    1  1 2   2   -3-    5   
       0           0  0 1   1   1 2  --4-- 
                        0   0   0 1  2  -3-
                                  0  1  1 2
                                     0  0 1
                                          0
```

Since we're doing BFS, we'll actually stop at the first zero like follows and not build the deeper parts of the tree:

```
   --------10------
   5         -----9--------
---4---     -3-     ------8------  
2    -3-    1 2     4           7        
1    1 2    0
```

However we can reduce the number of branches further by the B&B heuristic to look like this (*and this makes a huge difference on massive numbers*):

```
   --------10------
   5         -----9--------
   4         3            8
   2         1            7
             0
```

**Time Complexity:** `O(log n)` **Space Complexity:** `O(log n)` <sup>(I think)</sup>

Below is python 3 code with input of 1 googol (10^100) which takes about 8 seconds to run on my computer and around ~350 MB of RAM. You can also run it online at https://repl.it/B3Oq/76

```
from collections import deque

def number_of_steps(i):
    Q = deque()
    seen_before = set()
    steps = 0
    Q.append((i, steps))
    while True:
        j, steps = Q.popleft()
        if j == 1:
            return steps
        if j % 3 == 0:
            branch(Q, seen_before, steps, j // 3)
        if j % 2 == 0:
            branch(Q, seen_before, steps, j // 2)
        branch(Q, seen_before, steps,  j - 1)

def branch(Q, seen_before, steps, k):
    if k not in seen_before:
        seen_before.add(k)
        Q.append((k, steps + 1))

import time
n = 10**100
print('input:', n)
start = time.time()
steps = number_of_steps(n)
end = time.time()
print('runtime (seconds):', end - start)
print('number of steps:', steps)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is fast dynamic programming solution :-

```
minSteps(N) = Minimum(minSteps(N/3),minSteps(N/2),minSteps(N-1)) + 1
```

**Note:** If N is not divisible by 3 or 2 then dont include it in the DP equation.

**Time Complexity :** `O(N)` 
**Space Complexity :** `O(N)`

Java Code for DP solution :-

```
public static int decompose(int n) {
        int steps [] = new int[n+1];
        steps[1] = 0;
        for(int i=2;i<=n;i++) {
            int min = n;
            if(i%2==0) {
                min = Math.min(min,steps[i/2]);
            }
            if(i%3==0) {
                min = Math.min(min,steps[i/3]);
            }
            min = Math.min(min,steps[i-1]);
            steps[i] = min + 1;
        }
        int k =n;
        System.out.println("Steps:");
        while(k>1) {
            if(k%3==0&&steps[k/3]+1==steps[k]) {
                System.out.println("div 3");
                k=k/3;
            }
            else if(n%2==0&&steps[k/2]+1==steps[k]) {
                System.out.println("div 2");
                k=k/2;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("minus 1");
                k=k-1;
            }
        }

        return(steps[n]);

    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't know a better approach, but I wouldn't say this is 'fast'. `O(N)` is exponential in the size of the input (since `N` can be encoded with `log N` bits). The only really fast algorithm to this problem must be some greedy approach . Note that if we omit the first rule there is an easy solution to go to 1 in `O(log N)` steps: divide by 2 when even, subtract 1 when odd. So that is an obvious upper bound for the full problem.

Comment: @Heuster I meant it is faster than something exponential in N which we get if you do brute force. Yes the following solution is pseudo polynomial like knapsack but like knapsack it is a hard problem. And you as mentioned O(logN) is lower bound(you wrote upper bound) but dont know of any algorithm that achieves it.

Comment: I meant upper bound on the number of steps :-) by only using rules 2 and 3, the optimal number of steps is exactly (looking at the binary representation of the number) `number of 1 bits - 1 + position of highest 1 bit`, because the most significant bit must be shifted right by dividing by 2 (`position of highest 1 bit` times) and every other bit must be eliminated by subtracting 1 at the appropriate step. Adding rule one might lead to fewer elimination steps, so you can bound the search space.

Comment: @Heuster Yes it is upper bound to no of steps but to use branch & bound you might need a lower bound because we are finding minimum steps. log3(N) is a lower bound but not that tight i assume.

Answer (score 0):

Treat this as a breadth-first tree traversal.

The root node is N.  The operations are the edges that lead to its children,

Stop when you reach a 1.

The path from the root to the 1 is the solution.

Comment: But won't a breadth first search through a ternary tree get really slow really fast?

Comment: @mbeckish Maybe you would prefer dijkstra's shortest path than BFS to get the shortest path which would take O(NlogN) to get the shortest path from root to one but still slower than DP solution.

Comment: @Teepeemm - It might, but there could be a lot of short-circuiting because most numbers will not be divisible by both 2 and 3.  Also, since there is a lot of dividing being done, I imagine the depth will be somewhere around log N (where N is the given integer).